# Google Apps Sript buttons

Tags: button, google-apps-script, containers

I am trying to make a sidebar that automatically writes sentences in to a daily activity report. In security officers repetitively document things. I basically want to make it easier. Click a button and a pre-written auto time-stamped sentence pops up.

I got a side bar.

But when I try to exceed three buttons the whole thing fails. The HTML side bar pops up. But the buttons stop working.

The FUNCTIONS behind the buttons still work when I run them using the IDE play button. But the buttons stop reacting when I exceed three buttons.

Thanks for ANY help, and let me know if you would like to see my code.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: The majority of "on topic" and good questions will always have code.  You are a new member, and new members often do not understand what the expectations are.  If you have a specific and unique problem that you can describe well, then that is a candidate for a good question.  The number of buttons may be totally immaterial to why your code fails.  I'm not saying that there isn't some correlation to the button number, but correlation is not causation.  If you are using Chrome or Firefox, press the f12 key from the tab with your document, and the web developer tools will open at the bottom.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the log of the console?  Use `console.log('variableName: ' + variableName)` to print variable values to the browser console.  Read the [Troubleshooting Guide for Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of a timestamped text input into a spreadsheet from a sidebar.

Code.gs

```
function onOpen()
{
  loadSideBar();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu').addItem('loadSidebar', 'loadSideBar').addToUi();  
}

function dispText(txt)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Notes');
  var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-6', "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var row=[];
  row.push(ts);
  row.push(txt);
  sht.appendRow(row);
  return true;
}

function loadSideBar()
{
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}
```

sidebar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#txt1').val('');
      });
    function sendText()
    {
      var txt=$('#txt1').val();
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(clearText)
        .dispText(txt);
    }
    function clearText()
    {
      $('#txt1').val('');
    }
    console.log("My code");
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <textarea id="txt1" rows="12" cols="35"></textarea><br /><br />
  <input id="btn1" type="button" value="submit" onClick="sendText();" />

  </body>
</html>
```